# How to store multiple values in to objects within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, array.prototype.map

Problem:

I have an api and each object within the api doesn't have a value. I would like to add a unique value to each object within the array so that I can create a function and use 'e.target.value' with event listeners. I'm doing this in nextjs.

Why:
Because I want to store each value in to an array and localstorage before eventually displaying the data that was stored in the array as like a favorites item.

Is there a way of doing this ?

Information:

data.items has over 30+ objects -

```
"items": [
    {
      "id": 119603782,
      "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTk2MDM3ODI=",
      "name": "react-contextual",
      "full_name": "drcmda/react-contextual",
      "private": false,
      "owner": {
        "login": "drcmda",
        "id": 2223602,
}

{
      "id": 119603782,
      "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTk2MDM3ODI=",
      "name": "react-contextual",
      "full_name": "drcmda/react-contextual",
      "private": false,
      "owner": {
        "login": "drcmda",
        "id": 2223602,
}
```

So far my data has been sorted and mapped like so.

```
{data.items
          .sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.stargazers_count - a.stargazers_count && new Date (b.created_at) - new Date(a.created_at) 
          })
          .map((d) => (
            
            <div onClick={checkId} key={d.id} className=" border-white p-5">
              
              <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Repo name: {d.name}</h1>
```

Comment: Why not just use the index as a unique key in the array If it is just for display purpose?

Comment: how? And, what would happen if I added a new object ? would it lose it's index position meaning the incorrect favorited element would be displaying?

Comment: If a new item is added. the new item index is increased by 1. No conflict, right?

Comment: could you show me a working example please

Comment: I leave an answer as a example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example using index as unique for displaying purpose.

```js
const data = {
    items: [
        {
            id: 119603782,
            node_id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTk2MDM3ODI=",
            name: "react-contextual",
            full_name: "drcmda/react-contextual",
            private: false,
            owner: {
                login: "drcmda",
                id: 2223602,
            },
        },
        {
            id: 119603782,
            node_id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTk2MDM3ODI=",
            name: "react-contextual",
            full_name: "drcmda/react-contextual",
            private: false,
            owner: {
                login: "drcmda",
                id: 2223602,
            },
        },
    ],
};

const items = data.items.map((item, idx) => ({ ...item, idx }));

// new item
const newItem = {
    id: 119603782,
    node_id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTk2MDM3ODI=",
    name: "react-contextual",
    full_name: "drcmda/react-contextual",
    private: false,
    owner: {
        login: "drcmda",
        id: 2223602,
    },
};

function addNewItems(items, newItem) {
    newItem.idx = items.length;
    items.push(newItem);
    return items;
}

console.log(addNewItems(items, newItem));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want add a **VALUE** key to each object you can do the following:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false),
    [items, setItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            //you can replace axios with fetch
            const res = await axios('https://your-api'),
                // clone deep is from lodash => you can use the spread (...) operator if you want
                clonedItems = cloneDeep(res.data.items);

            clonedItems.forEach((el) => {
                // add whatever you want in the (value)
                el.value = 'required value';
            });
            //sort items based on the required key
            clonedItems.sort((a, b) => {
                //replace name with your key
                if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
            //check the modified items
            console.log(clonedItems);

            setItems(clonedItems);
        } catch (err) {
            //replace it with your error handler code
            console.log(err);
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    })();
}, []);
```

Notes:

- You should sort your elements before storing it in the state
- You can replace axios with fetch
- you can use the spread operator (...) in place of cloneDeep from lodash